# Compare two multidimensional arrays in PHP to sum datas

Tags: php, arrays

I've two arrays:

**Array A:**

```
$rates = array(
    'apple' = array(
        'red'    => 1.19,
        'green'  => 0.99,
        'yellow' => 0.89
    )
);
```

**Array B:**

```
$cart = array(
    'apple' = array(
        '0'  => red,
        '1'  => green
    )
);
```

---

The array B is the cart one and I need to get rates from Array A.

So:

- Apple > red > `1.19`
- Apple > green > `0.99`

Total should be `2.18`.

---

This is what I tried:

```
foreach($cart as $key => $arr){
    if(!in_array($key[$arr], $rates)){
        $total += $rates[$key];
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

What I'm missing please ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. Firstly, you should be checking whether the product type from `$cart` exists as a key in `$rates` i.e.

```
if(!in_array($key[$arr], $rates)){
```

should be:

```
if (isset($rates[$key])) {
```

Secondly, once you have determined that the key does exist in `$rates` you then need to iterate over each of the values in `$arr` to get their price from `$rates` (using the null coalescing operator to avoid problems with values not being in the rates array):

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($cart as $key => $arr) {
    if (isset($rates[$key])) {
        foreach ($arr as $value) {
            $total += $rates[$key][$value] ?? 0;
        }
    }
}
echo $total;
```

Output:

```
2.18
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/eSn3C)

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$rates = array(
    'apple' => array(
        'red'    => 1.19,
        'green'  => 0.99,
        'yellow' => 0.89
    )
);
$cart = array(
    'apple' => array(
        '0'  => 'red',
        '1'  => 'green'
    )
);

$total = 0;
foreach($cart as $type => $items) {
    if(array_key_exists($type, $rates)) {
        foreach($items as $item) {
            if(array_key_exists($item, $rates[$type])) {
                $total += $rates[$type][$item];
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $total;
?>
```